QAbstractListModel: how to create a nested model?
For the context, I have the following application structure in QML: StackLayout with nested Repeater, which has a model and a delegate. This delegate has a few string fields, but also needs another model, because delegate will contain ListView with another fields.
// qml
StackLayout {
    Repeater {
        model: NameModel {
        }
        delegate: NameDelegate {
            name: model.name
            secondName: model.secondName
            // anotherModel: model.anotherModel ???
        }
    }
}

I'm not sure how could I achieve that. I read in Qt docs that maybe I could use QVariantList, since it also could become model in QML, but I'm not sure how could I put or retrieve data into QVariantList.
I prepared some basic model for my strings, but I have no idea how can I add another nested model inside?
// namelist.h
struct NameItem {
  QString name;
  QString second_name;
  // another model ???

  bool operator==(const NameItem& other) const {
    return name == other.name && second_name == other.second_name;
  }
};

class NameList : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  explicit NameList(QObject* parent = nullptr);

  QVector<NameItem> items() const;
  bool                                              setItemAt(int index, const NameItem& item);
  bool                                              setItems(const QVector<NameItem>& items);

 private:
  QVector<NameItem> _items;

 signals:
  void preItemsSet();
  void postItemsSet();
};

// namelist.cpp
#include "namelist.h"

NameList::NameList(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {}

QVector<NameItem> NameList::items() const {
  return _items;
}

bool NameList::setItemAt(int index, const NameItem& item) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= _items.size()) {
    return false;
  }

  const NameItem& old_item = _items.at(index);
  if (item == old_item) {
    return false;
  }

  _items[index] = item;

  return true;
}

bool NameList::setItems(const QVector<NameItem>& items) {
  emit preItemsSet();
  _items = items;
  emit postItemsSet();
  return true;
}

// namemodel.h
#pragma once

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class NameList;

class NameModel : public QAbstractListModel {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(NameList* list READ list WRITE setList)

 public:
  explicit NameModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);

  enum { NameRole = Qt::UserRole, SecondNameRole };

  int           rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
  QVariant      data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
  bool          setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
  Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
  virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
  NameList*    list() const;
  void                           setList(NameList* list);

 private:
  NameList* _list;
};


// namemodel.cpp
#include "namemodel.h"

#include "namelist.h"

NameModel::NameModel(QObject* parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent), _list(nullptr) {}

int NameModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
  if (parent.isValid() || !_list) {
    return 0;
  }

  return _list->items().size();
}

QVariant NameModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {
  if (!index.isValid() || !_list) {
    return QVariant();
  }

  const NameItem item = _list->items().at(index.row());
  switch (role) {
    case NameRole:
      return QVariant(item.name);
    case SecondNameRole:
      return QVariant(item.second_name);
  }

  return QVariant();
}

bool NameModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role) {
  if (!_list) {
    return false;
  }

  NameItem item = _list->items().at(index.row());
  switch (role) {
    case NameRole:
      item.name = value.toString();
      break;
    case SecondNameRole:
      item.second_name = value.toString();
      break;
  }

  if (_list->setItemAt(index.row(), item)) {
    emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

Qt::ItemFlags NameModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const {
  if (!index.isValid()) {
    return Qt::NoItemFlags;
  }

  return Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> NameModel::roleNames() const {
  QHash<int, QByteArray> names;
  names[NameRole]    = "name";
  names[SecondNameRole] = "secondName";
  return names;
}

NameList* NameModel::list() const {
  return _list;
}

void NameModel::setList(NameList* list) {
  beginResetModel();

  if (_list) {
    _list->disconnect(this);
  }

  _list = list;

  if (_list) {
    connect(_list, &NameList::preItemsSet, this, [this]() { beginResetModel(); });
    connect(_list, &NameList::postItemsSet, this, [this]() { endResetModel(); });
  }

  endResetModel();
}


The most logical solution would be to use a QAbstractTableModel with further fields in the subsequent columns, or QAbstractItemModel with child items for each top level parent used in the list view.

Hmm, I think QAbstractTableModel is a wrong approach, since it helps with accessing data in grid like structures, but my case contains data with nested list with another data, but maybe I'm wrong.
https://pastebin.com/qeLkcN4x
I found something like this, but I'm not sure how could I add my top level strings to that model? I tried replacing QVector<QVector with something like QVector, where OuterData contained QVector, but it didn't work at all.

It's not that wrong if you think about it. Each of your items is part of a one dimension array, with each item having a further one dimension array. As long as the "nested" item count is identical, you can have the same result as in a table, with the main index (the first column) being the "root" of the further model, then you can just hide the first item in the "child" list. In any case, a tree structure would certainly be more consistent and appropriate, it just complicates things a bit.

If you only want one level of hierarchy you could also make an extra role next to NameRole and SecondNameRole that just returns the QVariantList from the data() function

I thought about that. So let's say I have QVariantList wrapped over list of my struct, so QVariant is a wrapper for a struct. I assign list as a model to a view in QML. How can I access specific field of that struct in QML?

All QObject derived classes can be used in qml.
Of course, you need to pass it as a QVariant.
You can use the function QVariant::fromValue() to return as data of your NameModel class, another QAbstractListItem derived class.
Below, an example:
QVariant NameModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {
  if (!index.isValid() || !_list) {
    return QVariant();
  }

  const NameItem item = _list->items().at(index.row());
  switch (role) {
    case NameRole:
      return QVariant(item.name);
    case SecondNameRole:
      return QVariant(item.second_name);
    case AnotherModelRole: // A new role
      return QVariant::fromValue(&item.another_model); // Address to a QAbstractListModel derived class
  }

  return QVariant();
}

N.B.

Check also index.row() < _list->items().size(), this is not guaranteed from a valid index.

pays attention to the ownership and the parent/child relationship of the another_model class.

remember that a QObject derived class CANNOT be copied



Yup, that's seems to be the way. I came up with a similar solution, but I used two QAbstractListModels. I created another model and list similar to NameList and NameModel. In NameItem I created another field of a type std::shared_ptr<AnotherList>, which simplifying setting up that field (uncopyable QObject derived class).
In data() I return QVariant::fromValue(item.list.get());.
In setData() I could simply do item.list = value.value<std::shared_ptr<AnotherList>>(); (not sure about this one, but I'm never setting it from QML anyway).
Everything else is basically the same.

It makes sense, but pay attention that you are breaking the smart pointers features by using the get() function. Maybe is better to store the other model simply as a pointer and let the parent/child relationship manage its lifecycle
